# setTimeout removeClass

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `setTimeout` to remove both class. Don't work!

Am I missing something?

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#teacher').removeClass("yellow");
} {
    $('#student').removeClass("black");
}, 2000);
```

and `span` two diffrent `id`

```
<span id="teacher">Mellisa</span>
<span id="student">John</span>
```

Comment: Check your console.....................it should be  `setTimeout(function() {
    $('#teacher').removeClass("yellow");
    $('#student').removeClass("black");
}, 2000);`

Comment: You need to remove the `} {` in the middle

Others: Please mark as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: there is no class `yellow and blue`

Answer (score 0):

You closing the callback function after the first class remove.

```
setTimeout(function() 
   {
     $('#teacher').removeClass("yellow");
     $('#student').removeClass("black");
   }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE
  - Html Elements are accessed by class names or IDs.

```
<span id="teacher">Mellisa</span>
<span id="student">John</span>


 setTimeout(function() {
$('#teacher').removeClass("yellow");
$('#student').removeClass("black");
}, 2000);
```